# How to position a link near bootstrap icon?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **span12** container and I have **3X span4**

I put an **icon** and a **link** to each **span3**.

However, I couldn't position the link to the center of the image.

This is the code

```
<div class="span3">
                        <div class="span4"><i class="icon-print icon-4x"></i></div>
                        <div class="span8"><a href="#">KEŞİF FORMU</a></div>
                    </div>
```

This is the image

[image]

I just want to vertically align the link to the icon. I think I tried every method but I couldn't succeed.

This is MY [WEBSITE](http://www.carantina.com) to view live demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to adjust the link line-height:

```
line-height:4;
```

Or something along those lines, fiddle around with it